# Computer heating and NVIDIA 940MX drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, overheating

I recently install ubuntu on a dual boot with windows 10, because i need it for college. I've formated a lot because the drivers wont work properly. but on the first time when i installed the NVIDIA drivers for 940MX, however it was tearing a lot and heating, so i went to nvidia x server settings on "PRIME settings" ans change for intel graphics, and it worked. but now i have installed the NVIDIA drivers(384.59)(i tried other but. nothing) but when a enter the settings it not even show "PRIME settings" ans it is heating up.

My settings:

Intel i5 7200U

NVIDIA 940MX GDDR5 2gb

8GB DDR4

Comment: on windows i don't have any problems with overheating, only when i play games, but its normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realize that to show PRIME settings you have to disable `Secure Boot` in the BIOS Settings